# Find the words do not appear in the dictionary in linux platform

Tags: linux, bash

Here's the text maybe have some words ,each line has one word.and I accept it as a command line arguments. For example the textile `a.txt` is like:

```
about
catb
west
eastren
```

And what I want to do is to find the words do not in the dictionary, if the words are dictionary words, delete it in the textfile. 
I use the following commands:

```
word=$1
grep "$1$" /usr/share/dict/linux.words -q
for word in $(<a.txt) 
do
  if [ $word -eq 0 ]
  then
    sed '/$word/d' 
  fi
done
```

Nothing Happened.

Comment: You code misses at least one pipe. But even with the missing pipe you can not iterate with `sed` twice over an input stream. If you consume it in the first run, it is empty in the second run. I would say the whole program is nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

`grep` alone is enough from what I understand

```
$ grep -xvFf /usr/share/dict/linux.words a.txt 
catb
eastren
```

`catb` and `eastren` are words not found in `/usr/share/dict/linux.words`. The options used are

```
   -x, --line-regexp
          Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is
          like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.

   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated  by  newlines,
          any of which is to be matched.

   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the
          -e  (--regexp)  option,  search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and
          therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: I think your command is available to my example, but I tried in the real situation, it outputs all the words in the text, not just the words don't appear in the dictionary.

Comment: @luven you'll have to provide sample where it doesn't work.. I don't quite get what you are trying to say... so create two sample files without involving `/usr/share/dict/linux.words` and show the case that doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to check a real text? `grep -f` searchs line by line, so you can only have one word per line, which you stated in your question is the case.

Comment: `++` for demonstrating to use `/usr/share/dict/linux.words`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a spell checker like `hunspell`, so you can apply it to any text, not only a pre-formatted file with only one word per line. You can also specify several dictionaries, and it shows only words which are in none of them.

For example, after copy/pasting the content of this page into `test.txt`

```
lang1=en_US
lang2=fr_FR
hunspell -d $lang1,$lang2 -l test.txt | sort -u
```

produces a list of 46 words:

```
'
Apps
Arqade
catb
'cba'
Cersei
ceving
Drupal
eastren
...
WordPress
Worldbuilding
xvFf
xz
Yodeya
```